# Losing application context in @controller when adding @Around advice and exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-aop

At first I code a RestController with ExceptionHandlers and everything works well. When I added an advice that wrap my @RequestMapping (with @Around) it broke my ExceptionHandler. When exception is thrown. E.g., TypeMisMatchException, All of a sudden, my controller lost its autowired beans (all of them are null).
I added a check in @PostConstruct and saw that my controller actually wires the beans.

MyRestContoller:

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyRestController implements MyRestControllerInterface<Throwable> {


    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired private FirstBean firstBean;
    @Autowired private SecondBean secondBean;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        //just to print that beans are auto wired properly
        //All beans are ok
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value=“/”, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> postData(@SuppressWarnings("unused") @PathVariable ValidVersion version, @RequestBody DataRequest dataRequest) throws Throwable {
        //stuff
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newObj, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    private ErrorInfo handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        log.error("Error serving URL '" + req.getRequestURL()+ "': ", e);
        //do something with firstBean
        //but if thrown with configured advice the firstBean is null, 
        //and secondBean and applicationContext...
        //
        return new ErrorInfo(ErrorCodes.InternalServerError, req.getRequestURL().toString(), null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

My Aspect:

```
@Service
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

@Autowired private GraphiteBeanReporter graphiteBeanReporter;

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void restController() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.sample.MyRestController.*(..))")
    public void methodPointcut() {}


    @Around("restController() && methodPointcut()")
    public Object whatToDoAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    String metricName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    log.trace("inside the aspect of method '{}', metricName);
    Context time = graphiteBeanReporter.initAndStartTimerMetic(metricName);
    try {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (time != null)
            time.stop();
    }

}
```

Just to add more information 
The MyRestController and SomeAspect beans are configured in MVCCOnfig.class
while other business logic beans (i.e. FirstBean, SecondBean and more) are configured in AppConfig.class
My Initializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    public WebAppInitializer() {
        // stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class, AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MVCConfig.class };
    }
}
```

**Edit**
added the implementation of whatToDoAround advice. It's basically report metric ('timer') to Graphite server using autowired bean. As I mentioned, if no exception is thrown in the controller, the metric is reported as expected.

**Update** - 
specifically, `ValidVersion` is an enum that represent my API valid versions. An Exception is thrown where in the url `@PathVariable` is set with unknown String (one that can't be converted to enum value). This exception doesn't trigger any of my advices. I even tried to use `@AfterThrowing` without any success.

Comment: I forgot to add that if no exception is thrown, the advice works as expected.

Comment: Might not be related, but I would not mix controller and controlleradvice. The advice is applied to all controllers.

Comment: What is your aspect doing, add the implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum see the implementation.